# View schema of resultset in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there any way in Sql Server Management Studio (2008) whereby I can view the data types of each field in the result of a query?

In this case, I am running a stored procedure which returns a result set, and I would like to know the lengths of the nvarchar columns and precision of decimals.

In the past, I have created a view which contains the underlying query in the stored procedure, and then viewed the column list, but the query within the procedure is much too complex to do so in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick and dirty snippet, requires all the fields in the result set are named or aliased;

```
select * into #T 
from 
  openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'exec thedb.dbo.sp_whatever')
exec('use tempdb exec sp_columns #T drop table #T')
```

Comment: Identical approaches and a dead heat - sorry I can't mark both as an answer. Points to Alex K for Server=. and sp_columns being more specific than sp_help. Many thanks.

Comment: You must enable "Ad-hoc distributed queries" to use this feature:

    sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
    sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet may be to use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to store the output of the procedure into a table, then examine that table. Something like:

```
SELECT * INTO YourHoldingTable 
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=YourServerName;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourProcedureName')
GO

sp_help 'YourHoldingTable'
GO

DROP TABLE 'YourHoldingTable'
GO
```