# Can an SSMS add-in have access to a resultset?

Tags: ssms, ssms-2012, ssms-addin, ssms-2014

Can an SSMS add-in have access to resultsets?  I would like an add-in tools menu item that can generate into the clipboard a `DECLARE @Result1 TABLE ( ... )` (including the name, type, length, precision, etc) for each of the results in the most recently returned resultset.  I see some discussions about accessing the result Grid UI directly, but by then some of the metadata would have to reconstructed from the grid values rather than from the resultset directly.

It seems to me that such an add-in would be useful when intermediate results need to be captured into an intermediate value for reuse, not having to go look up all those column types from all the joins.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to get the results from your addin? I'm searching the internet for the same thing but nothing comes up. Can you point me to the discussions about accessing the Grid UI you mentioned in the question so I can search from there?

Comment: Well, here's a script I use now to give me the types in sql and c#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440123/how-to-determine-the-datatypes-of-the-results-of-a-sql/30057314#30057314  I don't remember where I saw the thing about accessing the grid.