# How can I know data type before SQLBindCol() in ODBC C?

Tags: c, odbc

I want to do like this,

if(data type is char)

```
SQLBindCol(hStmt, i+1, SQL_C_CHAR, data[i], sizeof(data), &nulldata[i]);
```

else if(data type is float)

```
SQLBindCol(hStmt, i+1, SQL_C_FLOAT,&fData[i], sizeof(fData), &nulldata[i]);
```

So how can I know data type?.?

Comment: Use [SqlDescribeCol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldescribecol-function).  There is a good example of using it [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/examples/DescribeAndBindColumns.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a variable is of a certain type (compare two types) in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c)

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [How to determine the datatypes of the results of a SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440123/how-to-determine-the-datatypes-of-the-results-of-a-sql/440192#440192)

Comment: wowww you saved my whole time.
I searched this problem about 4 hours.
I appreciate you help.